# Select box to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

On my form I am trying to have my select box take up the row except enough room to show the button on the same row.

I am after a responsive design, so as I resize the page then of course with size of the select box should resize as well to take into account that size.

I can set a percentage on the select, but as it goes up and down sometimes I end up with a large gap, or the button goes onto a new line.

```
html

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="droplist">Select item:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <select id="droplist">
                <option>Value 1</option>
                <option>Value 2</option>
            </select>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Action!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

css
select {
    width: 80%;
}
```

Is there a way to have both the select and the button on the same line, and the select just resizes with the page?

fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/sJT6C/

Comment: Is something bad with setting the button width, too?

Comment: Well, if the button only needs 100px and I set a percent then it could be 200px which is a waste...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you insist on the button having fixed width, you can use advanced CSS layouts (flex or grid, [now experimental in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display)) or alter the HTML markup and play with `float` CSS property as follows.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="droplist">Select item:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Action!</button>
            <div class="wrapper">
            <select id="droplist">
                <option>Value 1</option>
                <option>Value 2</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: .5ex;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
}
button {
    float: right;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJT6C/2/)

In the markup, I swapped the `select` and the `button` and wrapped the `select` in a `div` with class `wrapper`. The wrapper is needed to get the `select` to take as much space as possible, without specifying its width. (If `width: 100%` is specified without a wrapper, there will be no room for the button.)

The stylesheet tells `select` to stretch to the full width of its parent, which is `.wrapper`. The wrapper has no width specified, but as a block element it tries to take as much space as possible. Now we have a `select` that behaves like a well-behaved block element.

Now the floating part. The wrapper is given right margin of the size of `button` width (including padding and border). *It would be best to ensure that the button never exceeds this size, but I did not focus on that.* The `button` is told to float to the right. Thus it fills the space reserved by wrapper’s right margin. (If I did not swap the elements in markup, the button would move down by the height of the wrapper.)

*And yeah, I forgot to mention the `margin-top: .5ex` of `.wrapper`. Originally `select` and `button` used to have their baselines aligned. My hack breaks this alignment and this margin is quite a poor attempt to fix it. Vertical alignment is a darn complicated thing in CSS and I did not find it important enough to really solve it here.*

Comment: Thank you, I resolved the verticle align with a line-height of 30 on the label, since the labels are going to be single line anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Palec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601271/695786), if you have a variable width for your button (or buttons), then margin-right will not be an adequate solution. Instead, replace with the overflow attribute:

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: .5ex;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
}
button {
    float: right;
}
```

(HTML unchanged from original answer)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgs8cc7f/2/)

It is important that the button element is placed before the select box. It will not work the other way around (though I have not been able to determine why that is).

**Note:** this solution (like Palec's) will result in the tab index of the elements being reversed: the button will be tabbed to first, then the select box.