# Why does overflow hidden only work when elements are in a specific order?

Tags: html, css

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24600471/695786), the intent is to have a select box and button on the same line, with the select box width filling all available space.

This can be achieved with the following HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="droplist">Select item:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Action!</button>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <select id="droplist">
                    <option>Value 1</option>
                    <option>Value 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: .5ex;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
}
button {
    float: right;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgs8cc7f/2/)

If the button is moved to be after the wrapper div - which to me is the structurally intuitive place for it - then the button is pushed onto the next line.

The question is:
**Why does reversing the order of the button and wrapper div elements cause the button to shift to a new line?**

Comment: The title of your question doesn't really match the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the button width is not set, to automatically fill up the width, you will need to apply flexbox to the `col-xs-9` container.

```css
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: .5ex;
  flex: 1;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="droplist">Select item:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <select id="droplist">
          <option>Value 1</option>
          <option>Value 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Action!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

EDIT:

As for why your code does not work, it's because you are floating everything right so the button is placed first to the right, followed by you `wrapper` which DOES NOT have a width set. So `overflow: hidden` manages to keep the `select` element in the same line. If you remove the `overflow`, the `select` element will move to the next line.

When you reverse the order of `wrapper` and `button`, the `wrapper` is set first to the right and as the `child` `select` element has a `width` of 100%, it fills up the entire space, since wrapper has no width set, the overflow is pointless. Hence the `button` wraps to the next line

Comment: The original code already fills up the length. Question is regarding reversing the elements. Clarified question.

Comment: The original code does not achieve what you want. You wanted "button is after the wrapper div". That's what my answer shows.

Comment: No, the original code shows what works (at least for me on Chrome). The question is why moving the button after the wrapper div breaks it.

Comment: I think your edit is close to the correct answer. However, only the button is floated right, not everything. The first part of your answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It's a bit of a mystery, but my best guess would be that, as CSS is cascading, when the button is before, it would now about the button's size when the 'float reflow' is done, so the div width is adapting according to the button. But if the button is after, CSS doesn't know, and the width takes all the space available.

You should always set a width on floated items (except if applied directly to an image – which has implicit width). If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable.

Another workaround could be to use `display: table`

```css
.col-xs-9 {
  display: table;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: .5ex;
    width: 100%;
}
select {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper,
button {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="droplist">Select item:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
           
            <div class="wrapper">
              <select id="droplist">
                <option>Value 1</option>
                <option>Value 2</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            
             <button class="btn btn-primary">Action!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The question is more to do with why its necessary to place the button after the div for the overflow/float instructions to work expected. Clarified the question.